# Toggle menu problem in html/css website menu. Can't get menu while hovering the cursor on hamburger icon at the right

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I am having problem with the toggle button in the menu, when @media (max-width = 1200px),. i.e. When i toggle on to the toggle button, nothing appears. Please help

I have added bootstrap 4.3 in the html script. The menu which i want to add to the toggle button which i have created is below the toggle button in my html script. Please help me solve this

```css
ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*********************************
*** Marque
*********************************/
.marquee {
  background: #2a4563;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  /*border: 1px;
    border-left: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FF5733 ;*/
}

.marquee a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

/*********************************
*** Logo Bar
*********************************/
#logo-bar {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 3px;
}

#logo-bar .logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo-bar .logo img {
  max-width: 280px;
}

#logo-bar .logo-2 img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#menu {
  background: #2a4563;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 3px -3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
}

#menu ul li:hover, .active {
  background-color: orange;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#menu ul li:hover a {
  color: black;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li ul li ul.nav-sub-sub-item{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: orange;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.nav-sub-sub-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #2a4563;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: ease-in .3s;
}

label {
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 70px;
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
}

/*
Media Queries for Hamburger Menu
*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .logo-bar {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile-menu {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .mobile-menu-1 {
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  }

  .mobile-menu-1 img {
    max-width: 200px;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
    pointer: cursor;
  }

  #menu ul li {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEB;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #toggle:checked+#menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Home Style Sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Libre+Baskerville|Montserrat|Quicksand|Raleway|Slabo+27px&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0412137e5c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js'></script>
  <script src='script/script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Sample Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->

  <!-- Marquee Starts -->
  <div class="marquee">
    <marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4" direction="left" class="marqueeStyle" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
      <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> Everything will remain closed upto 30th May 2020 to avoid gathering &amp; prevention of spreading Novel Corona Virus </a>
    </marquee>
  </div>
  <!-- Marquee Ends-->
  <!-- Logo Bar Starts -->
  <header class="header">
    <div id="logo-bar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-bar">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="logo col-lg-6 col-md-6">
              <a href="index.html">
                <h1>LOGO</h1>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="logo-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <h1>@2ND LOGO</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Student Login</button>&nbsp;<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Admin Login</button>
              <h6><strong>Call Us:</strong> +41-320-00000000</h6>
              <h6><Strong>Email Us:</Strong></h6>
              <h6>info@example.com</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mobile-menu-1 col-10 d-flex my-auto">
          <h1>Mobile LOGO</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="mobile-menu-2 col-2 d-flex my-auto">
          <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Logo Bar Ends -->
    <!-- Menu Bar Starts -->
    <div id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">About Us</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="about.html">About TGU</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="vision.html">TGU Vision</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="mission.html">TGU Mission</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="board.html">Board of Mgt.</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Approval & Affiliation</a>
                <ul class="nav-sub-sub-item">
                  <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/tgu-act.pdf" target="_blank">TGU Act</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="pdf/UGC-consolidated-list.pdf" target="_blank">UGC List</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Academic</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="department.html">Department</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="course.html">Courses</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="syllabus.html">Syllabus</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Admission</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="procedure">Procedure</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="applyonline.html">Apply Online</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="scholarship.html">Scholarship</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="download.html">Download Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="merit.html">Merit</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#!">Examination</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="examform.html">Exam Form</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="examnotice.html">Exam Notice</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="admitcard.html">Admit Card</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="verification.html">Verification</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="research.html">Research</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Library</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">WiFi Campus</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Hostel & Cafe</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Digitalization</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">First Aid</a></li>
              <li class="nav-sub-item"><a href="#!">Sports</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="search_button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


  <!-- Menu Bar Ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a form checkbox to create the toggling logic which is not a valid use of the HTMl tag. what you should be doing is adding a JS logic to the div element `mobile-menu-2` to bind add a click event handler to it.

HTML

```html
<div class="mobile-menu-2 col-2 d-flex my-auto">&#9776;</div>
```

JS

```js
var mobileMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-menu-2")[0];
//Add click event with a callback function to toggle class style
mobileMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  var activeMenu = mobileMenu.classList.contains("active");
  if (!activeMenu) {     
    mobileMenu.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    mobileMenu.classList.remove("active");
  }
}
```

So what this will do is add and remove a class on your div element called active. So now in your CSS you would need to just make sure you have the right styles applied to the class that you're targeting.

Example CSS

```css
.mobile-menu-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.mobile-menu-2.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

If you need to add/remove an active state class on another div you just need to target that new element `document.getElementsByClassName('something')[0]` and add/remove the class to this new element.

Comment: the javascript doesn't seems to work with my html/css. Please if you can elaborate .

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the JS to have the correct format. Should be working now